# Vagrant LoadError on OSX

Tags: macos, installation, vagrant

I am trying to install vagrant. After installation terminal command gives error.

Tried cleaning([docs link](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/installation/uninstallation.html)) and installing again.

I only install and try to run `vagrant` command from terminal. 
This is what i get. I have no idea what it means.

```
/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- vagrant-share/helper/api (LoadError)
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-share-1.1.7/lib/vagrant-share/activate.rb:244:in `<encoded>'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-share-1.1.7/lib/vagrant-share/activate.rb:16:in `RGLoader_load'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-share-1.1.7/lib/vagrant-share/activate.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-share-1.1.7/lib/vagrant-share.rb:23:in `block in <class:Plugin>'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:75:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:75:in `block (2 levels) in help'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/registry.rb:49:in `block in each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/registry.rb:48:in `each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/registry.rb:48:in `each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:69:in `block in help'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/optparse.rb:917:in `initialize'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:57:in `new'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:57:in `help'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:32:in `execute'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:308:in `cli'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.4/bin/vagrant:127:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with your `vagrant-share` plugin (v. 1.1.7)
you can install latest version of the plugin

```
$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-share --plugin-version 1.1.8
Installing the 'vagrant-share --version '1.1.8'' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Fetching: vagrant-share-1.1.8.gem (100%)
Installed the plugin 'vagrant-share (1.1.8)'!
```

and it should work after this

Comment: /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/generic.rb:1100:in `rescue in merge': URI must be ascii only "?gems=\u{2013}plugin-version" (URI::InvalidURIError)

Comment: It tries to install 1.1.7.

Comment: right because I missed the double `--` for plugin-version, can you try again with `vagrant plugin install vagrant-share --plugin-version 1.1.8`